# Add missing rows based on logic Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to know if it's possible add missing rows in Power Query depending on a certain logic, for example I have a table like this:

Material    Year    Month   Value

A1  2019    12  500

A1  2020    2   505

A1  2020    5   506

A1  2020    10  507

And I need it to fill the missing rows so it can be like this:

Material    Year    Month   Value

A1  2019    12  500

A1  2020    1   500

A1  2020    2   505

A1  2020    3   505

A1  2020    4   505

A1  2020    5   506

A1  2020    6   506

A1  2020    7   506

A1  2020    8   506

A1  2020    9   506

A1  2020    10  507

So it's to fill the missing months and also copy the value from the previous month.

If I need to explain it better please let me know.

Thank you!